# Using the jquery .on() and $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have buttons that will be repeatedly destroyed and re-rendered. I am trying to use `.on()` to do this, as it works for elements not yet created. I suspect the syntax is correct, jslint finds no errors. It breaks some of the javascript on the page, but not all of it. I've never used `.on()`. I'm unsure why it shows no errors on jslint, but breaks some of my browser, and why it only breaks some of my browser.

Here is my jQuery. In this case, #showPrevious is what is being destroyed and re-rendered.

```
$("#showPrevious").on( "click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "flip/showprevious.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#showContainer").html(html);             
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why not use $("#divid").click() instead?

Comment: can you create a fiddle so we can see full code?

Comment: That's my old version, but it only works if the element hasn't been destroyed and recreated yet. Once it's re-rendered, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can i ajax inside of a jsfiddle? I'd need to destroy and re-render the button that will be clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation on delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()

To do something like this, you attach the event handler on a parent element to the element being added/removed.

For example:

```
$( "#aParentSelector" ).on( "click", "#showPrevious", function() {
  // $.ajax({ ... }) etc
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It's still not working. As a matter of fact, it's broken my chat feature elsewhere on the site, however other ajax features on the site still work. I don't know why that is, but perhaps something is unique about this situation. Besides the javascript I posted, what should I be looking for? Because it is a large project, I don't think posting it all on here is a good option.

Comment: The change I suggested should have no impact on other code. 

You're correct in not posting all the javascript, there's probably too much code to read. To try and fix your issues, I would debug the javascript to find out what is happening and when, break on exceptions and put some breakpoints in strategic places.